# passing an array through data-dojo-props attribute

Tags: html, dojo

I'm trying to make a custom dojo widgit that i've inherited from another developer html5 compliant.  Currently i pass an attribute to the constructor like this:

```
 <div id="aGrid" 
     dojoType="gswidgets.search.Grid" 
     style="width: 100%;" 
     pageName="the grid page"  
     simplePageFieldTranslations="{appNumber:'applicationNumber',orgName:'organization'}"
     rowKey="applicationID" 
     defaultCriteriaValues="dictionary">
</div>
```

Now to bring this up to standards these properties will need to passed through the data-dojo-props attribute.  However i've run into an issue with the "simplePageFieldTranslations" since it is an array.

```
<div id="aGrid"
   dojoType="gswidgets.search.Grid"
   style="width: 100%;"
   data-dojo-props="pageName: 'a grid',
simplePageFieldTranslations:{appNumber: 'applicationNumber' , orgName:'organization'},
   rowKey: 'applicationID',
   defaultCriteriaValues:'dictionary'
">
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?  I normally work in java and this is my first foray into the dojo world so i really appreciate any help.

The error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
note: [ opened at line 1, column 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wywF.png)

Comment: is there an error in console , if so post it heer

Comment: Yes, i added it to the original post.  For some reason it does not see the ending curly brackets.

Comment: I know the data-dojo-props accepts a javascript object literal without the external curley brackets {} but there still seems to be an issue with how its being parsed.  Is my notation off? I've looked online and as far as i can tell its good.

Answer (score 0):

In you example simplePageFieldTranslations is an object, not an array.

Try this way:

```
 <div id="aGrid"
   data-dojo-props="
     pageName: 'a grid',
     simplePageFieldTranslations:[
       {appNumber: 'applicationNumber' , orgName:'organization'}
     ],
     rowKey: 'applicationID',
     defaultCriteriaValues:'dictionary'
   ">
 </div>
```

There is nothing very special in passing arrays with data-dojo-props:

Take a look here: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kstepanov/91pfxohr/5/)

Comment: @Krilill thanks for the suggestion but i am still getting the same error.  in the constructor the field translations are defined as such simplePageFieldTranslations: {}.

Comment: the error includes this       dojo/_base/json/</dojo.fromJson
http://localhost:8082/gs/dojo_v17/dojo/      which is why i thought it was an issue parsing the object.

Comment: @kgswim It can be tricky to understand dojo  exceptions.  You could post full exception and call stack in your question, but not sure we'll be able to figure out what's going on there.

Comment: Here is a screen shot of the error and trace (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wywF.png).

Comment: I fixed this by passing each attribute through its own "data-dojo-props" attribute.